# Difficulty with understanding summations

Tags: summation

I am in advance sorry if this question is too easy for this site, but I am having real problem understanding how to solve this summation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n{i*2^i}$$

I understand basics of summations but i don't know where to start, please help.

Comment: This exact question has been asked on this website many times (although it's not so easy to find anything on this site).

Comment: I looked but didn't find anything, everything was much more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you write $$\sum_{i=1}^n{i*2^i}$$ as $$x\sum_{i=1}^n{i*x^{i-1}}$$The term which is in the summation is the derivative of  $$\sum_{i=1}^n{x^{i}}=\frac{x \left(x^n-1\right)}{x-1}$$ which is a geometric progression. So, compute the derivative of the rhs with respect to $x$, multiply the result by $x$ and replace $x$ by $2$.

I am sure you can take from here.